# Can an output voltage of a simple comparator be higher than the input voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, comparator, pspice

[image]

This is a simple comparator circuit that I have built for a school project. However, for some reason, the output voltage tends to be higher than the input voltage of 12 volts(accidentally cut out in the picture, so it looks like 2V). It comes out as 15V, which I have no clue why.

Is there a reason for this, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you supplying the comparator with 15 volts?

Comment: Hyuntaek Woo - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the main site rules in the [tour] & [help] as they differ from typical forums. (b) Please [edit] your question and add the part number of U7 (you call it a comparator, the schematic labels it as an op-amp), as well as showing its supply rail voltage, as requested in the comment above. (c) What do you mean that the output voltage "tends to be higher than the input voltage". Under what condition *is* it higher, and what condition is it *not* higher? Please explain clearly and in more detail, by improving the question. Thanks.

Comment: You should show the power supplies to the opamp (and model) on your schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the opamp supply, but when used as a comparator with no negative feedback, the op-amp output will go from one extreme (the negative supply or ground if single supply) to the other (the positive supply) depending on which input is the most positive.

Exact output voltage and current drive levels depend on the op-amp model, with some supporting rail-to-rail drive, with others only getting within a diode drop at decent currents.

True comparators (as opposed to opamps) are optimizer for the extreme to extreme switching, and speced in terms of *speed*, whereas opamps are normally designed to operate in between the supply voltages and are defined in terms of *gain-bandwidth*.

When a opamp is used as a comparator it may take significant time to recover from drive to the rails.